# what is this kind of frames, vlan, SMLT?

Tags: ethernet, libpcap, packet-sniffers, data-link-layer

i've coded a sniffer with libpcap dealing with data link layer. but i've implemented only the ethernet part. Since this morning, i receive this kind of frame all day long. Could you help me to find the protocol used there and the layer ?
Thx

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF 0A 61 FC 80 B6 EF 26 00 00 00 AF 81 01 00 61 65 72 6F 68 69 76 65 20 67 72 61 74 75 69 74 6F 75 73 20 61 72 70 2C 20 61 70 5F 6D 61 63 3D 66 34 65 61 3A 62 35 36 35 3A 33 61 30 30 2C 20 69 70 3D 31 30 2E 31 33 36 2E 31 2E 34 34 2C 20 73 65 71 3D 32 37 65 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

> FF FF FF FF FF FF

destination MAC

> 0A 61 FC 80 B6 EF

source MAC

> 26 00

Ethertype

> 00 00 AF 81 01 00 61 65 72 6F 68 69 76 65 20 67 72 61 74 75 69 74 6F 75 73 20 61 72 70 2C 20 61 70 5F 6D 61 63 3D 66 34 65 61 3A 62 35 36 35 3A 33 61 30 30 2C 20 69 70 3D 31 30 2E 31 33 36 2E 31 2E 34 34 2C 20 73 65 71 3D 32 37 65 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Data: ÿÿÿÿÿÿ
aü¶ï&¯**aerohive gratuitous arp**, ap_mac=f4ea:b565:3a00, ip=10.136.1.44, seq=27ea

Comment: And what is that ? I dunno find anything

Comment: Apparently, it's a GARP frame from some Aerohive access point.